# Tabs are not working with more than one on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using PHP. I am getting the product data from the database and displaying like a tab wise.

Now I have a script which is not working with multiple tabs section. It's working only for the first tab section and I have more than 6 tabs section. I am getting the issue on  `$('.tab-content').removeClass('current');` because it's removing the current class form the everywhere.

If I click on the first tab of the first tab section then it's removing the current class from the 2-6 tab sections.

I tried  something like

`$('.products-category-list').closest('.tab-content').removeClass('current');`

Would you help me out with this issue?

```
<?php while ($stmt->fetch()) { ?>
<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="products-category-list">
      <div class="a-tab">
        <ul class="tab_click">
          <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-<?php echo $product_slug ?>1">Product1 Details</li>
          <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-<?php echo $product_slug ?>2">Product2 Details</li>
          <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-<?php echo $product_slug ?>3">Product3 Details</li>
          <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-<?php echo $product_slug ?>4">Product4 Details</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="tab-<?php echo $product_slug ?>1" class="tab-content current">
        <div class="display_table">
          <p>
            <?php echo $productdetails1 ?>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-<?php echo $product_slug ?>2" class="tab-content">
        <div class="display_table">
          <p>
            <?php echo $productdetails2 ?>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-<?php echo $product_slug ?>3" class="tab-content">
        <div class="display_table">
          <p>
            <?php echo $productdetails3 ?>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-<?php echo $product_slug ?>4" class="tab-content">
        <div class="display_table">
          <p>
            <?php echo $productdetails4 ?>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<?php }$stmt->close();?>
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.tab_click li').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
     $(this).closest('ul.tab_click').find('li').removeClass('current');
   $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
  })

});
```

Comment: Hi can you add the html code which is generated by php code willhelp us to solve issue

Comment: @Rishab, Sorry I can't get you. HTML code is also in the question. I am sharing the sample of the code in this link https://jsfiddle.net/k6c2urdz/  I am referring this only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your jsfiddle, I would replace your javascript bit with :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $(this).closest('ul.tabs').find('li').removeClass('current');
        $(this).closest('.container').find('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    })
})
```

So I replaced the line

```
$('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
```

with

```
$(this).closest('ul.tabs').find('li').removeClass('current');
```

to only select the li of the current tabs, same for the line

```
$('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
```

Comment: Give me some time to check  your answer

Comment: I think your answer is working for me. Give some time to implement with my code. I will update you ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('ul.tab_click').find('li').removeClass('current');
```

replace the above code with:

```
$('ul.tab_click li').removeClass('current');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not working. because It's also removing the current class from second tab section.

Comment: That's the tab functionality. removes for all tab current class and only adds for clickable element.